# R display first 10 rows of data of certain columns?

Tags: r

In R - say I have a dataset (data) with the columns "mpg", "car", "cylinders". Is there a way to display the first 10 rows of data for just "mpg" and "car"?

`head(data,10)` works fine, but displays all 3 columns - I wasn't sure if there was a way to display less columns without actually subsetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
head(data[c("mpg","car")],10)
```

or

```
head(data,10)[c("mpg","car")]
```

Answer (score 2):

To subset your data use `[rows, columns]`:

Try one of the following:

```
head(data,10)[,1:2]

head(data,10)[,c("mpg","car")]
```